unable to remove the skype ppa
I have upgraded from ubuntu 22.04 -> 24.04 and I have some issues with the skype repo. I uninstalled the skypeforlinux but the repo...I can't remove it.
On every update I get this error:
Err:5 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 2a02:26f0:3500:c84::1263 443]
Fetched 1.080 kB in 7s (144 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch https://repo.skype.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 2a02:26f0:3500:c84::1263 443]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I tried to remove the ppa like this:
sudo add-apt-repository --remove https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main

but I get this error:
Repository: 'deb https://repo.skype.com/deb noble stable main'
Description:
Archive for codename: noble components: stable,main
More info: https://repo.skype.com/deb
Removing repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 364, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 355, in main
    shortcut.remove()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuthandler.py", line 233, in remove
    self.remove_source()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuthandler.py", line 349, in remove_source
    sourceslist.save(remove=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/extendedsourceslist.py", line 391, in save
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list'

How can I remove the skype ppa???
UPDATE
The output of ps -ea
 PID TTY          TIME CMD
      1 ?        00:00:01 systemd
      2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
      3 ?        00:00:00 pool_workqueue_release
      4 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-rcu_g
      5 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-rcu_p
      6 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-slub_
      7 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-netns
      8 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:0-events
     10 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:0H-events_highpri
     11 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u64:0-netns
     12 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-mm_pe
     13 ?        00:00:00 rcu_tasks_kthread
     14 ?        00:00:00 rcu_tasks_rude_kthread
     15 ?        00:00:00 rcu_tasks_trace_kthread
     16 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/0
     17 ?        00:00:00 rcu_preempt
     18 ?        00:00:00 migration/0
     19 ?        00:00:00 idle_inject/0
     20 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/0
     21 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/1
     22 ?        00:00:00 idle_inject/1
     23 ?        00:00:00 migration/1
     24 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/1
     25 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:0-events
     26 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:0H-events_highpri
     27 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/2
     28 ?        00:00:00 idle_inject/2
     29 ?        00:00:00 migration/2
     30 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/2
     31 ?        00:00:00 kworker/2:0-events
     32 ?        00:00:00 kworker/2:0H-events_highpri
     33 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/3
     34 ?        00:00:00 idle_inject/3
     35 ?        00:00:00 migration/3
     36 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/3
     38 ?        00:00:00 kworker/3:0H-events_highpri
     39 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/4
     40 ?        00:00:00 idle_inject/4
     41 ?        00:00:00 migration/4
     42 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/4
     44 ?        00:00:00 kworker/4:0H-events_highpri
     45 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/5
     46 ?        00:00:00 idle_inject/5
     47 ?        00:00:00 migration/5
     48 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/5
     49 ?        00:00:00 kworker/5:0-events
     50 ?        00:00:00 kworker/5:0H-events_highpri
     51 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/6
     52 ?        00:00:00 idle_inject/6
     53 ?        00:00:00 migration/6
     54 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/6
     56 ?        00:00:00 kworker/6:0H-events_highpri
     57 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/7
     58 ?        00:00:00 idle_inject/7
     59 ?        00:00:00 migration/7
     60 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/7
     62 ?        00:00:00 kworker/7:0H-events_highpri
     63 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/8
     64 ?        00:00:00 idle_inject/8
     65 ?        00:00:00 migration/8
     66 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/8
     68 ?        00:00:00 kworker/8:0H-events_highpri
     69 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/9
     70 ?        00:00:00 idle_inject/9
     71 ?        00:00:00 migration/9
     72 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/9
     74 ?        00:00:00 kworker/9:0H-events_highpri
     75 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/10
     76 ?        00:00:00 idle_inject/10
     77 ?        00:00:00 migration/10
     78 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/10
     80 ?        00:00:00 kworker/10:0H-events_highpri
     81 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/11
     82 ?        00:00:00 idle_inject/11
     83 ?        00:00:00 migration/11
     84 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/11
     86 ?        00:00:00 kworker/11:0H-events_highpri
     87 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/12
     88 ?        00:00:00 idle_inject/12
     89 ?        00:00:00 migration/12
     90 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/12
     91 ?        00:00:00 kworker/12:0-events
     92 ?        00:00:00 kworker/12:0H-events_highpri
     93 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/13
     94 ?        00:00:00 idle_inject/13
     95 ?        00:00:00 migration/13
     96 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/13
     98 ?        00:00:00 kworker/13:0H-events_highpri
     99 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/14
    100 ?        00:00:00 idle_inject/14
    101 ?        00:00:00 migration/14
    102 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/14
    104 ?        00:00:00 kworker/14:0H-events_highpri
    105 ?        00:00:00 cpuhp/15
    106 ?        00:00:00 idle_inject/15
    107 ?        00:00:00 migration/15
    108 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/15
    109 ?        00:00:00 kworker/15:0-rcu_par_gp
    110 ?        00:00:00 kworker/15:0H-events_highpri
    113 ?        00:00:00 kdevtmpfs
    114 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-inet_
    116 ?        00:00:00 kauditd
    117 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:2-events
    119 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:2-rcu_par_gp
    120 ?        00:00:00 khungtaskd
    121 ?        00:00:00 oom_reaper
    123 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-write
    124 ?        00:00:00 kcompactd0
    125 ?        00:00:00 ksmd
    126 ?        00:00:00 khugepaged
    127 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-kinte
    128 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-kbloc
    129 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-blkcg
    130 ?        00:00:00 irq/9-acpi
    132 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-tpm_d
    133 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-ata_s
    134 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-md
    135 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-md_bi
    136 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-edac-
    137 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u64:1-ext4-rsv-conversion
    138 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-devfr
    139 ?        00:00:00 watchdogd
    140 ?        00:00:00 kworker/1:1H-kblockd
    142 ?        00:00:00 irq/25-AMD-Vi
    143 ?        00:00:00 kswapd0
    144 ?        00:00:00 ecryptfs-kthread
    145 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-kthro
    146 ?        00:00:00 irq/26-aerdrv
    147 ?        00:00:00 irq/27-aerdrv
    148 ?        00:00:00 irq/28-aerdrv
    149 ?        00:00:00 irq/29-aerdrv
    150 ?        00:00:00 irq/31-aerdrv
    152 ?        00:00:00 kworker/4:1-events
    154 ?        00:00:00 kworker/6:1-mm_percpu_wq
    155 ?        00:00:00 kworker/7:1-events
    158 ?        00:00:00 kworker/11:1-events
    159 ?        00:00:00 kworker/12:1-events
    160 ?        00:00:00 kworker/13:1-mm_percpu_wq
    161 ?        00:00:00 kworker/14:1-rcu_par_gp
    163 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-acpi_
    166 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-mld
    167 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-ipv6_
    169 ?        00:00:00 kworker/5:1H-kblockd
    175 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-kstrp
    177 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u67:0-hci0
    178 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u68:0-ttm
    192 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-charg
    218 ?        00:00:00 kworker/6:1H-kblockd
    220 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:1H-kblockd
    234 ?        00:00:00 kworker/13:1H-kblockd
    240 ?        00:00:00 kworker/9:1H-kblockd
    263 ?        00:00:00 kworker/2:1H-kblockd
    264 ?        00:00:00 kworker/12:1H-kblockd
    265 ?        00:00:00 kworker/7:1H-kblockd
    266 ?        00:00:00 kworker/15:1H-kblockd
    267 ?        00:00:00 kworker/11:1H-kblockd
    268 ?        00:00:00 kworker/3:1H-kblockd
    269 ?        00:00:00 kworker/10:1H-kblockd
    270 ?        00:00:00 kworker/8:1H-kblockd
    273 ?        00:00:00 kworker/14:1H-kblockd
    275 ?        00:00:00 kworker/4:1H-kblockd
    288 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-nvme-
    289 ?        00:00:00 kworker/14:2-events
    296 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-nvme-
    297 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-nvme-
    301 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-nvme-
    324 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_0
    325 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-scsi_
    326 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_1
    327 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-scsi_
    328 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_2
    329 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-scsi_
    330 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_3
    331 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-scsi_
    332 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_4
    333 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-scsi_
    334 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_5
    335 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-scsi_
    336 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_6
    337 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-scsi_
    338 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_7
    339 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-scsi_
    342 ?        00:00:15 kworker/u66:4+events_unbound
    348 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_8
    349 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-scsi_
    350 ?        00:00:16 kworker/u66:10-events_unbound
    352 ?        00:00:00 kworker/4:2-rcu_par_gp
    355 ?        00:00:00 kworker/7:2-cgroup_destroy
    358 ?        00:00:00 kworker/8:2-mm_percpu_wq
    378 ?        00:00:00 jbd2/nvme0n1p2-8
    379 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-ext4-
    420 ?        00:00:00 psimon
    425 ?        00:00:00 systemd-journal
    449 ?        00:00:00 kworker/2:2-rcu_par_gp
    455 ?        00:00:00 kworker/9:2-events
    503 ?        00:00:00 kworker/9:3-events
    506 ?        00:00:00 systemd-udevd
    508 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u65:4-writeback
    574 ?        00:00:00 psimon
    626 ?        00:00:01 kworker/u65:9-events_power_efficient
    635 ?        00:00:19 kworker/u65:17-flush-259:0
    636 ?        00:00:06 kworker/u65:18-events_unbound
    661 ?        00:00:00 kworker/5:2-events
    702 ?        00:00:00 kworker/3:2-events
    771 ?        00:00:00 kworker/10:2-events
    780 ?        00:00:00 ccp-1-q2
    781 ?        00:00:00 ccp-1-q3
    782 ?        00:00:00 ccp-1-q4
    783 ?        00:00:00 hwrng
    893 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-crypt
    929 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u67:1-hci0
   1027 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-nvkm-
   1028 ?        00:00:00 kworker/R-ttm
   1029 ?        00:00:00 card0-crtc0
   1030 ?        00:00:00 card0-crtc1
   1031 ?        00:00:00 card0-crtc2
   1032 ?        00:00:00 card0-crtc3
   1320 ?        00:00:00 systemd-oomd
   1377 ?        00:00:00 systemd-resolve
   1379 ?        00:00:00 systemd-timesyn
   1508 ?        00:00:00 accounts-daemon
   1509 ?        00:00:01 acpid
   1510 ?        00:00:00 anacron
   1512 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon
   1514 ?        00:00:00 bluetoothd
   1515 ?        00:00:00 cron
   1516 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
   1523 ?        00:00:00 networkd-dispat
   1528 ?        00:00:01 polkitd
   1532 ?        00:00:00 power-profiles-
   1545 ?        00:00:02 snapd
   1550 ?        00:00:00 switcheroo-cont
   1558 ?        00:00:00 systemd-logind
   1563 ?        00:00:00 udisksd
   1573 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon
   1581 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager
   1588 ?        00:00:00 wpa_supplicant
   1629 ?        00:00:00 ModemManager
   1642 ?        00:00:00 rsyslogd
   1773 ?        00:00:00 unattended-upgr
   1788 ?        00:00:00 containerd
   1793 ?        00:00:00 anydesk
   1869 ?        00:00:00 colord
   1874 ?        00:00:00 cupsd
   1919 ?        00:00:04 mysqld
   1966 ?        00:00:00 apache2
   1971 ?        00:00:00 apache2
   1972 ?        00:00:00 apache2
   1973 ?        00:00:00 apache2
   1974 ?        00:00:00 apache2
   1975 ?        00:00:00 apache2
   2148 ?        00:00:00 cups-browsed
   2166 ?        00:00:00 dockerd
   2176 ?        00:00:00 nmbd
   2198 ?        00:00:00 kerneloops
   2203 ?        00:00:00 kerneloops
   2209 ?        00:00:01 teamviewerd
   2247 ?        00:00:00 smbd
   2265 ?        00:00:00 smbd-notifyd
   2266 ?        00:00:00 cleanupd
   2267 ?        00:00:00 samba-bgqd
   2533 ?        00:00:00 gdm3
   2575 ?        00:00:00 rtkit-daemon
   2677 ?        00:00:00 upowerd
   2680 ?        00:00:07 packagekitd
   2821 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u68:1-ttm
   2893 ?        00:00:00 gdm-session-wor
   2902 ?        00:00:00 kworker/3:3-inet_frag_wq
   2909 ?        00:00:00 systemd
   2914 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
   2926 ?        00:00:00 pipewire
   2927 ?        00:00:00 pipewire-media-
   2928 ?        00:00:00 pulseaudio
   2937 ?        00:00:00 gnome-keyring-d
   2950 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
   2952 ?        00:00:00 xdg-document-po
   2958 ?        00:00:00 xdg-permission-
   2964 ?        00:00:00 fusermount3
   3004 tty2     00:00:00 gdm-wayland-ses
   3007 tty2     00:00:00 gnome-session-b
   3054 ?        00:00:00 gnome-session-c
   3068 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd
   3076 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-fuse
   3079 ?        00:00:00 gnome-session-b
   3107 ?        00:00:00 at-spi-bus-laun
   3111 ?        00:00:34 gnome-shell
   3119 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
   3157 ?        00:00:00 gnome-shell-cal
   3163 ?        00:00:00 evolution-sourc
   3170 ?        00:00:00 goa-daemon
   3171 ?        00:00:00 dconf-service
   3176 ?        00:00:00 evolution-calen
   3177 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-udisks2-vo
   3188 ?        00:00:00 goa-identity-se
   3201 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-gphoto2-vo
   3205 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-goa-volume
   3209 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-afc-volume
   3214 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-mtp-volume
   3220 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-trash
   3231 ?        00:00:00 gjs
   3232 ?        00:00:00 at-spi2-registr
   3251 ?        00:00:00 sh
   3252 ?        00:00:00 gsd-a11y-settin
   3255 ?        00:00:00 gsd-color
   3256 ?        00:00:00 gsd-datetime
   3258 ?        00:00:00 gsd-housekeepin
   3260 ?        00:00:00 ibus-daemon
   3262 ?        00:00:00 gsd-keyboard
   3263 ?        00:00:00 gsd-media-keys
   3266 ?        00:00:00 gsd-power
   3268 ?        00:00:00 gsd-print-notif
   3269 ?        00:00:00 gsd-rfkill
   3270 ?        00:00:00 gsd-screensaver
   3272 ?        00:00:00 gsd-sharing
   3277 ?        00:00:00 gsd-smartcard
   3278 ?        00:00:00 gsd-sound
   3282 ?        00:00:00 gsd-wacom
   3283 ?        00:00:00 blueman-applet
   3304 ?        00:00:00 evolution-alarm
   3343 ?        00:00:00 ibus-memconf
   3344 ?        00:00:00 ibus-extension-
   3351 ?        00:00:00 gsd-disk-utilit
   3356 ?        00:00:00 ibus-portal
   3397 ?        00:00:05 snap-store
   3429 ?        00:00:00 kworker/15:4-events
   3430 ?        00:00:00 ibus-engine-sim
   3443 ?        00:00:00 gsd-printer
   3453 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u68:3-ttm
   3462 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u68:12-ttm
   3463 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u68:13-ttm
   3464 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u68:14-ttm
   3465 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u68:15-ttm
   3471 ?        00:00:00 tracker-miner-f
   3479 ?        00:00:00 xdg-desktop-por
   3485 ?        00:00:00 xdg-desktop-por
   3494 ?        00:00:00 gjs
   3599 ?        00:00:00 snapd-desktop-i
   3658 ?        00:00:00 obexd
   3660 ?        00:00:00 blueman-tray
   3665 ?        00:00:00 xdg-desktop-por
   3668 ?        00:00:00 krfcommd
   3673 ?        00:00:00 snapd-desktop-i
   3711 ?        00:00:00 gjs
   3811 ?        00:00:01 fwupd
   3812 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-metadata
   4077 ?        00:00:10 insync
   4424 ?        00:00:00 QtWebEngineProc
   4425 ?        00:00:00 QtWebEngineProc
   4438 ?        00:00:00 QtWebEngineProc
   4448 ?        00:00:01 QtWebEngineProc
   4523 ?        00:00:00 kworker/13:3-rcu_par_gp
   5292 ?        00:00:06 Xwayland
   5298 ?        00:00:00 gsd-xsettings
   5344 ?        00:00:00 ibus-x11
   5502 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u69:3-ttm
   6035 ?        00:00:00 kworker/6:3-events
   6049 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u69:6-ttm
   6170 ?        00:00:00 update-notifier
   6361 ?        00:00:00 kworker/11:0
   6365 ?        00:00:00 kworker/10:0-cgroup_destroy
   6497 ?        00:00:00 kworker/8:0
   6500 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u69:2-ttm
   6504 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u69:7-ttm
   6505 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u69:8-ttm
   6506 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u69:9-ttm
   6507 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u69:10-ttm
   6508 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u69:11-ttm
   6511 ?        00:00:07 kworker/u66:0-events_unbound
   6512 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u68:4-ttm
   6514 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u68:6-ttm
   6516 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u68:8-ttm
   6517 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u68:9-ttm
   6518 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u68:10-ttm
   6519 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u68:11-ttm
   6617 ?        00:00:01 gnome-terminal-
   6635 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
   6765 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u65:0
   6767 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u66:1
   6775 ?        00:00:00 kworker/2:1-rcu_par_gp
   6776 pts/0    00:00:00 ps



Can you append to your question the output of 'ps -ea'

@david I have posted...

Try the following:
Open a terminal.
In it, run:
exec sudo -i
chattr -i -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
chmod ugo+w /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list 
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
apt clean
apt update
exit

Close the terminal

tried but: root@dev-machine:~# rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list': Operation not permitted 

now is working....thx :)

Could you please list the directory below and check for any file that might contain "skype" in its name, such as skype-stable.list?
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Use the following command to remove the Skype repository:
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list

Then, run:
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update

If you still encounter a PermissionError, it may be due to restricted permissions on the file. You can reset its permissions first if needed.

It does not allow to be removed .... tried with sudo ...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  162 sep 25  2023 skype-stable.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  162 nov  9 15:56 skype-stable.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  162 nov 12 10:14 skype-stable.list.save

Check the file attributes using the below command
lsattr /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
If you see an i attribute in the output , then remove it using
chattr -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
then, try remove the file again using rm command
